# Colleague lying about Covid-19 situation

Tags: colleagues, covid-19

I'm member of a small IT team in Europe, we're all working from home due to the COVID-19 situation. Last month one of my colleague stopped working because of the COVID-19. His wife caught the virus, he has to take care of her and the kids and therefore stopped working temporarily. Last week, my manager called him to see when he could come back working and he said he couldn't because his wife was still sick

Yesterday I was on social medias and I saw by accident a video of my colleague. In this video, we can see him with his wife playing a drinking game that's been popular on this social media recently. This video was made a few days before my manager called last week

Should I report this to my manager, and if yes, how ? I don't want to look like a stalker that checks on social medias if my co-workers are not lying ...

Comment: "This video was made a few days before my manager called last week"  How do you know when the video was made?

Comment: I think this question is nearly impossible to answer as it doesn't have a right or wrong answer and is a matter of opinion

Comment: @sf02 you can see the date the video was published. Also the "game" is popular since the lockdown, so there're no doubt the video was made recently

Comment: @JacobVanHolland A video can be filmed today and published two months from today.  The lockdown has been ongoing for several weeks.  If you are going to accuse someone of lying, you better make sure that you have indisputable evidence.

Comment: Is your colleague even getting paid while staying home? Where I live, that might be possible to somehow class as sick leave to watch their kids... but certainly not without documentation. You cannot declare yourself to be sick (well, you can, but nobody would give you money for that) you need a doctors note.

Comment: If he stopped working, what is your problem? Is he taking holiday? Paid time off? Sick leave (even sick people can drink)? Unless he is being paid to work from home, I see no problem. Even then, I would expect that he can choose his own hours to work - and to drink. As his boss, I would not care, so long as he is achieving his usual output & getting the job done.

Comment: Btw, Jacob. If  you are posting under your real name, that's probably not a smart move. Also, as questions age they acquire a precise time stamp - hours & minutes. I hope that no one you work with sees that you posted to this site during working hours (if that is the case)

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica Even as of now, if you hover over "2 days ago", you get the precise time stamp.

Comment: When first posted, it just says "today", then "yesterday", but it soon decays into something more granular. Upvote for telling me about the tooltip; I wasn't aware of that (despite designing my own sites in exactly the same way).

Comment: LOL. Well, if you are a rat, then report him! If you hate him and want him to vanish from the earth, report him! Otherwise, mind your own business. What are you doing on social media anyway? Sounds like you are the productivity problem, not him.

Answer (score 5):

It's not your job to enforce the company's policies around sick leave.

It's their policies and their job to make sure they are obeyed. If the policy is "I trust every word someone says, no need for doctors notes or certificates" then that's bad, but not really your problem.

Be a model employee and let the people that get paid for it sort this out. He might enjoy short term benefits right now, but you stop thinking about that and instead enjoy the good feeling that you don't have to look back at every shadow and expect to be caught. That feeling is long term and worth more than a few days netflixing on the employers dime.

Comment: Denunciation is not a great value, anyway.